# Help with integration by parts with $\int^\infty_{log4} xe^{-x} dx + \int^\infty_{log4} xe^{\frac{-3x-log4}{2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int^\infty_{log4} xe^{-x} dx +  \int^\infty_{log4} xe^{\frac{-3x+log4}{2}} dx$$

For left integral and right integral
$$\\ \mbox{ Let } dv= e^{-x}dx,u=x,v=-e^{-x}, du=dx $$
For right integral
$$\\ \mbox{ Let } dv= e^{\frac{-3x+log4}{2}}dx,u=x,v=-2/3e^{\frac{-3x+log4}{2}}, du=dx $$

$$-xe^{-x}\bigg|_{log4}^\infty + \int^\infty_{log4} e^{-x}dx + 2/3xe^{\frac{-3x+log4}{2}}\bigg|_{log4}^\infty + \int^\infty_{log4} 2/3e^{\frac{-3x+log4}{2}}dx$$

$$ log4(-4) - e^{-x}|_{log4}^\infty - 2/3log4 e^{-2log4} + 4/9 e^{\frac{-3x+log4}{2}}|_{log4}^\infty$$

$$ log4(-4) - 4 - 2/3log4 e^{-log4} - 4/9 e^{-log4}$$

However when I add all these numbers up, I got a different number than around .2544, which is the correct answer. Could someone please help me with this to see what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer not 0.2544, I did it with another method. I wouldn't use integration by parts in this integral, rather I would solve
$$
I(a) = \int^\infty_{\log4} x e^{-ax} = \int^\infty_{\log4}  \frac{d}{da}\left(- e^{-ax}\right) = -\frac{d}{da}  \int^\infty_{\log4} e^{-ax} = 
-\frac{d}{da}\left( \frac{1- e^{-a\log{4}}}{a}\right) = \frac{ e^{-a\log{4}}+a\log{4}e^{-a\log{4}}}{a^2} = \frac{4^{-a}(1+a\log{4})}{a^2}
$$
(note this is only true if $a>0$). This derivation under the integral sign is usually very useful.

Now, noting also that 
$$
e^{-\frac{\log{4}}{2}}= (e^{\log{4}})^{-1/2}=4^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
you can write your integral as
$$
I(1)+\frac{1}{2}I(3/2)=\left(4^{-1}(1+\log{4})\right) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{4^{-3/2}(1+\frac{3}{2}\log{4})}{(3/2)^2} = \frac{1}{4}(1+\log{4}) + \frac{1}{36}(1+\log{8})
$$
which gives $0.682114\cdots$

Comment: WA yields the same.

Comment: True http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx+E%5E%7B-x%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+Log%5B4%5D%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D+%2B++++Integrate%5Bx+E%5E%7B-%283+x+%2B+Log%5B4%5D%29%2F2%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+Log%5B4%5D%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D+.

Comment: I am so sorry should be + 4...I just revised it....could you do it in integration by parts again?

Comment: @user111548 I didn't check carefully but I believe you did the integration by parts right. You just messed up evaluating the limits, for instance $- e^{-x}|_{log4}^\infty=-(0-e^{-\log{4}})=e^{-\log{4}} = \frac{1}{e^{\log{4}}} = 1/4$ and not $-4$.